# how to get user's pc ip in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I'm building a function in my website where users can add a post to their favorites.
The code that I'm using now is `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];` so my variable is like this:

```
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
```

but this seems to be getting the user's network ip, becouse all the computers that are on my network have the same favorites.

I want something that get's the devices's (Computer) IP address.

Comment: time for a new game plan

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You only have access to a user's public facing IP address - if the user is sitting behind a router, that will be the router's IP address. There is no way to get the internal IP address.

If there are multiple people on the network, behind the same router, they will all have the same public IP address.

Comment: You could look at `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` to grab the user's browser version. That might help you to get a tiny bit more specific behind the `REMOTE_ADDR`.

Comment: Side note; IP addresses can change too.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do it, is with users registration in your webpage. They can login and save your favorites associated with their username. A poor way, is using cookies ($_COOKIES).

You can't use IP address to store related information in public websites, unless it is an intranet and you're sure that your network computers have static IPs.

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty bad way to determine uniqueness of the clients connecting to your site.  You're probably seeing the WAN address, which is all you're going to get because a LAN structure is private.  Even if you did get the LAN IP address, they would not be unique.

You're better setting a cookie and using it via session_start() and $_SESSION.  Even better, create a small user account system (and don't forget to hash those passwords).

Answer (score 0):

This isn't how the internet works - if you aren't connected direct to the internet you will have some sort of internal IP for each computer on the network. This internal network is managed by some sort of router and creates the "internal network", you could say a very small internet. This "small internet" is connected to your ISP and gets a public IP adress, which is used by a *router* to *route* the internal traffic to the public internet, but only by using the *public* ip, not the *internal* ip.

What you could do is setting a seesion when the user visits your website and read it when he returns, this seesion will be unique and identifies a computer. in this seesion you could store all your data needed. How seesions work can be read [here](http://www.php.net/manual/de/book.session.php).

Illustration of a internal network:
[image: NAT]

I hope I could help a bit, sorry for my broken english, I'm from germany :)

Comment: Btw the seesions can get destroyed too, so it's not a real place to store data, you should use small databases or if you wan't to stay very small some sort of formarted text files.